# Nginx client_body_buffer_size and client_max_body_size optimizations for large POST requests

Tags: nginx

I have an API that receives anywhere from 1K to 20MB of data in each transmission. I also have a website that would only ever receive less than 10K in a single transmission. Both the API and the website are behind the same Nginx proxy server.

From the docs for `client_body_buffer_size`

> If the request body size is more than the buffer size, then the entire (or partial) request body is written into a temporary file."

This means that any time I receive a request over the default, it will be written to disk.

Given that I can receive large payloads, would it be best to set the `client_body_buffer_size` equal to `client_max_body_size`, which for me is 20MB? I assume this would prevent nginx from writing the request to disk every time.

Are there any consequences to setting the `client_body_buffer_size` so high? Would this affect the website, which never receives such large requests?

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend using a smaller `client_body_buffer_size` (bigger than 10k but not so much, maybe the x64 default of 16k), since a bigger buffer could ease DoS attack vectors, since you would allocate more memory for it, opposed to disk which is cheaper.

Please note that you can also set a different `client_max_body_size` and `client_body_buffer_size` on a specific server or location (see [Context](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_buffer_size)) so your website wouldn't allow 20MB uploads.

Here's an [interesting thread on `client_body_buffer_size`](http://nginx.2469901.n2.nabble.com/request-body-and-client-body-buffer-size-td7586681.html), it also reminds that if the client body is bigger than your `client_body_buffer_size`, the nginx variable $request_body will be empty.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "ease DoS attack vectors"?  Perhaps you meant "could increase DoS attack vectors".

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your server memory and how many traffic you have.

A simple formula: MAX_RAM = client_body_buffer_size X concurrent_traffic - OS_RAM - FS_CACHE.

(exactly the same thing with php-fpm pool tuning or even mysql/elasticsearch).

The key is to monitor all the things (RAM/CPU/Traffic) and change settings according your usage, star little of course then increase until you can.